# Bouncing custom table cell all the way to the top

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am struggling with a custom table cell which I need to move all the way to the top of the screen when its text field becomes first responder (not just somewhere above the keyboard where it automatically goes). This because I need some room for a suggestion drop down box in between the text field and the keyboard when the user starts typing.

I am not able to figure out how to attack this problem correctly :( Input will be greatly appreciated...

Thanks a lot,
Stine

Answer (score 0):

You should move the whole table, not just the cell. You can get the rect for the cell and move the table accordingly.

Comment: That was very fast, thanks a LOT! Yes, I guess I need to move the entire table as the "suggestive cell" is not the only cell in the table. Hmm, not sure I understand the thing with the rect - could you maybe be so kind to add a few more hints? :)

Comment: so if there are 4 rows showing, and the 4th row becomes FR, are you suggesting she translate the table so that the first 3 rows have a negative Y coordinate?  How would the user ever get those rows back?

Comment: You don't move the rows, you observe the KeyboardDidShow notification and work out the selected cell, then move the table up by the correct amount so that the selected cell is now at the top of the screen, the table will have a negative y position. You then observe the KeyboardDidDismiss (I think it is..will need to check) and move everything back down when the keyboard closes.

Comment: As for the rect, say the table is NORMALLY at y position 0.0. The cell you select is at y position 20.0 so you need to move the table to -20.0. However if your table starts at 30.0 and the selected cell is at 50.0 you need to move the table to -70.0. Does that make sense?

Comment: However, as stated, if the table is the only thing on the screen then you can scroll the table to the cells rect, it all depends what else you have on screen.

Answer (score 0):

UITableView has methods to do this: moveRowAtIndexPath.  There are lots of posts on SO that already cover this.  Try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230353/moverowatindexpath-in-uitableview-causes-incorrect-animation).

Edit:
You can also use the table scrolling methods to scroll the table to a row below the one you want.

```
 – scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:
 – scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition:animated:
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this by scrolling the table such that the cell containing the editing text field appears at the top of the visible table view - take a look at `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` in `UITableView`. Call it with `UITableViewScrollPositionTop` as the 2nd argument to achieve that effect. See also the UITableView [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/scrollToRowAtIndexPath%3aatScrollPosition%3aanimated%3a). For example:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    // quick and dirty way to obtain a reference to the cell containing the textField
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)textField.superview.superview;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                          atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop 
                                  animated:YES];
}
```

Then, you could add the 'suggestion drop down box' as a subview of your top-level view, making it appear above the tableView and positioning it accordingly.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    // assuming |suggestionBox| is a property owned by your controller
    if (![suggestionBox superview]) {
        // Set-up the suggestion box view here; have your controller retain it.
        // self.suggestionBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: ...];
        // ...

        // [self.view addSubview:suggestionBox];
    }   

    // Update the content of the suggestion box using the replacement string, e.g.: 

    // NSArray *suggestions = [self suggestionsWithString:string];
    // [self.suggestionBox setSuggestions:suggestions];

    return YES;
}
```

I wrote the code above in comments because it requires a few elements to be set-up, and that depends entirely on you. You would also have to make sure that you implement the appropriate logic to hide the suggestions drop down when it makes sense.

I hope this points you toward a working solution...